# Paypal-express gem, working in dev but not in prod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, paypal-sandbox, paypal

So I have an issue I can't figure out alone.

I have run some test on my app and when launch in dev it's working perfectly but as soon as it's on Prod and so it uses the real identificator, it doesn't work anymore.

I got this error:

`Paypal::Exception::APIError (PayPal API Error: 'Security error')`:
`/offers_controller.rb:218:in choose_step'`

```
  if Rails.env.production?
    response = request.setup(
        payment_request,
        "http://www.workiz.com/recruteurs/paypal_callback/" + params[:app_id],
        "http://www.workiz.com/recruteurs/offres",
        paypal_options  # Optional
    )
  else # Development ou Test
    response = request.setup(
        payment_request,
        "http://localhost:3000/recruteurs/paypal_callback/" + params[:app_id],
        "http://localhost:3000/recruteurs/offres",
        paypal_options  # Optional
    )
  end
```

That is the line that crash, so it's when I call request.setup

The request is created like that:

```
  if Rails.env.development?
    Paypal.sandbox!
    Paypal::Express::Request.new(
        username: ENV['PAYPAL_SANDBOX_USERNAME'],
        password: ENV['PAYPAL_SANDBOX_CLI_ID'],
        signature: ENV['PAYPAL_SANDBOX_SECRET']
    )
  elsif Rails.env.production?

    Rails.logger.info "Paypal SETUP PRODUCTION"

    Paypal::Express::Request.new(
        username: ENV['PAYPAL_USERNAME'],
        password: ENV['PAYPAL_CLI_ID'],
        signature: ENV['PAYPAL_SECRET']
    )
  end
```

And yes the logger "Paypal SETUP PRODUCTION" appear and the value set are the good one from the ENV variables.

I had to put Paypal.sandbox! in the config/development.rb to make it work for the sandbox but I cannot find a way to make it work for the production...

Any help is welcome. Thank you very much.

I have display the error, it look like that:

```
ERROR IS: #<Paypal::Exception::APIError::Response:0x007fa61661e040 
@raw={
:TIMESTAMP=>"2015-05-24T15:01:30Z", 
:CORRELATIONID=>"f3067f049ad", 
:ACK=>"Failure", 
:VERSION=>"88.0", 
:BUILD=>"1675131", 
:L_ERRORCODE0=>"10002", 
:L_SHORTMESSAGE0=>"Security error", 
:L_LONGMESSAGE0=>"Security header is not valid", 
:L_SEVERITYCODE0=>"Error"},

@ack="Failure", @build="16751317", @correlation_id="f3067f049a", @timestamp="2015-05-24T15:01:30Z", @version="88.0", @order_time=nil, @pending_reason=nil, @payment_status=nil, @payment_type=nil, @reason_code=nil, @transaction_type=nil, 
@error_code="10002", 
@severity_code="Error", 
@long_message="Security header is not valid", 
@short_message="Security error"
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct credentials for your production constants? Make sure the credentials you're using in production aren't the same as the sandbox credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Have a detailed look at the exception you're getting.

According to https://github.com/nov/paypal-express/blob/master/lib/paypal/exception/api_error.rb the error should have more useful information from the API response.

Simply catch the exception, and print it's contents:

```
begin
  response = request.setup...
rescue Paypal::Exception::APIError => error
  puts error.inspect
  raise error
end
```

You're probably missing some configuration in your PayPal account. The detailed error message and error code should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you, I have done that and edited the question with the additional informations

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have finally found my mistake.

It appear, you shouldn't use the CLI ID, PWD and SIGNATURE from the "live page" on your application.

But instead:

1. Log in to PayPal.com
   You must have a PayPal Business account to make calls to the live PayPal servers. Log in to your Business account on the following page: https://www.paypal.com.
2. Navigate to the API Access page
   Click the Tools tab and navigate to Manage your business > API Access.

Here you go, those are the good one... 
Very confusing !
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

**First,** double check that the 2 sets of credentials are different. You need a different account for sandbox than production.

```
PAYPAL_SANDBOX_USERNAME != PAYPAL_USERNAME
PAYPAL_SANDBOX_CLI_ID != PAYPAL_CLI_ID
PAYPAL_SANDBOX_SECRET != PAYPAL_SECRET
```

**Second,** double check that the production credentials are **correct**, i.e. no extra characters or typos.